# DC Power Connector type / model identification

Tags: power-supply, power, dc, connector, identification

I need to recreate this power supply and can't seem to find this connector - does anyone know what these are called?

I haven't tried to measure it, but suppose I could try to get some measurements if I could even find something that looked close.

The ring goes up over the jack end and "locks" so that the power can not be accidentally removed from the device, although that is not a strict necessity.  My other option I guess would be to remove the jack in the device and replace it with a known jack "barrel" type DC power.  Note that this is "keyed" because one side is positive and one is negative, so it can only be inserted one way.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: photo of connector]

Comment: Is that a D5/10-PC power plug? Which device it is from, AJA?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some type of [outdoor light system dc plug](https://www.google.com/search?q=outdoor%20light%20system%20connectors&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj08fvLw6DmAhXKzqQKHXoXC60Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=outdoor%20light%20system%20connectors&gs_l=img.12...0.0..155581...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz-img.Q0MTos0zl24&ei=AwfqXbTkBcqdkwX6rqzoCg&bih=937&biw=1920), but without dimensions/better pictures I can't be sure.